# django admin how to manipulate OneToMany related objects(not just inline)

Tags: django, django-admin, one-to-many

I have 2 models. 
One has a foreign key to another.

Say:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
```

I want to show all users who work in current organization in organizationAdmin, like a list of change links.

It should be possible

- to add new user
- to select existing user(no related to current organization) and set his organization to    current

No need to edit them inline

Just like permissions in userAdmin + adding and changing them

Is there any ready solution? Not to make forms by hands

Comment: well the ready solution is the admin panel, just add to it the models. and you have to do nothing, there are permitions in user section so other users that are not superusers may enter that section.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude):

```
class UserInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = User
    exclude = ['name', 'other_fields']
```

Or you can use ManyToMany relation:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)   

class Organization(model.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Comment: I should be able to 'select existing user and set his organization to current'

Comment: So you can use ManyToManyField, it will be perfect in your case.